# do spaces separate a string into different strings?

Tags: c, string

If I provide the string "Alice in wonder land" in the scanf statement, what would be the output of the following code (code at the bottom)? My book says the output should be:

```
Alice
in
wonder
land
```

Well, if I have provided "Alice in wonder land" as a single string, why is this the output? How can providing spaces in between the words "Alice", "in", "wonder", "land" make them separate strings when I am providing "Alice in wonder land" as a single string?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char s1[10], s2[10], s3[10], s4[10];
    scanf("%s%s%s%s", s1, s2, s3, s4);
    printf("\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s", s1, s2, s3, s4);
    getch();
}
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: 1) It wouldn't compile if you tried and 2) why don't you try?

Comment: You probably need a good C tutorial

Comment: @AdrianJandl there are no spaces in between consecutive %s

Comment: @PrashantSrivastava couldn't agree more :)

Comment: @JRG why? well, it did compile, and the output is exactly what the book says it should be...but i dont understand why.

Comment: As you wrote it, it would not compile.  Someone has helpfully fixed your code (you were missing a ").  To answer your question, that's how scanf works; http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how [`scanf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html) works. `%s` format specifier tells `scanf` to read until any white space, which includes any number of *spaces*, *tabs* or *enter* keys and store it in corresponding address.

From man, `%s` conversion specification,

> Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the input sequence and the terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added automatically. The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first

Answer (score 0):

From the [`scanf(3)` man page](http://manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/):

> Before conversion begins, most conversions skip white space

and:

> **`s`** Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters

Answer (score -1):

Your book rights.

when you get from a user a string with scanf, it stops reading when the first spase, tab or enter is in the input. and the rest of the input stay in the buffer.

Thats why you should'nt use scanf to read a string. You can use gets() function 
which stops at the first enter, which means that you can have space or tab in your input.

I asummed that you have not learned FILES yet, so it should be enough for now.